# How can i let my 0.2% proof stress pass by my shear stress/strain graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I'm supposed to plot 3 shear stress/strain curves for 3 materials, the other two materials have presented a reasonable graph except for cast iron. how could i let the line pass my black original graph?

```
[for k in range(0,3):
        I = np.pi*(radius_t\[k\]**4)/2 #polar moment of inertia
        Stress_torsion = \[ x*(radius_t\[k\])/I for x in torque \] #Pa
        Strain_torsion= \[ x*(radius_t\[k\])/l\[k\] for x  in angle \]
        Stress_torsion=np.array(Stress_torsion,dtype=float)
        Stress_torsion=Stress_torsion/10**6 #MPa
        #plot Stress_Strain torsional
    fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots()
    plot=ax1.plot(Strain_torsion,Stress_torsion,color='black')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Shear strain',size=15,fontweight='bold')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Shear stress  (MPa)',size=15,fontweight='bold')
    ax1.set_title('Torsion '+ torsion\[i\], size=10,fontweight='bold')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(torsion\[i\]+".png",dpi=300)][1]
```

[shows the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Ews.png)

Comment: Use higher values of torque?  Hard to know exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: im trying to find the intersection between those two lines and i need to show it,i cant use a higher set of torque